# jquery mobile data-transition="slide" is not working when using document.location.href = ""; insted of href=""

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile

I am presently trying to develop an website for mobile using jquery mobile.
Instead of `href=""` I am using `onclick="document.location= ""` to the link..

```
[example
<a onclick="document.location ='index.html';" title="back" data-transition="slide">Back</a>]
```

But data-transition is not working with this `document.location.href=""`..
Is there any solution, so that I can get the same transition effect when using `onclick="document.location= ""`..

And also `position:fixed` property is not working in android..Is there any solution so that it will work on the same..

Answer (score 5):

This is because Jquery Mobile intercepts your regular links and then loads the page via AJAX. It's only possible like this, because all the transition effects (including SLIDE) **require two pages to be in the DOM**.

Here is the link to [JQM's navigation model](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html)

As you can see, JQM hijacks a link, makes an AJAX-call to the new page and loads what's inside the *div.data-role="page"* on this page. The new page is appended to the DOM, so you have 2 pages in your document.

Then depending on your transition the new page position is set (for example on the top-left of your screen outside of the viewport). Then the transition happens, which slides in the new page above the old page. When done, the old page is hidden.

If, however you are doing a **document.location**, JQM will not intercept and just load the page you say without any Ajax and hence without any transition. This is the same as specifiying rel="external" on the link. Then it will also be a "normal" link without transitions.

To cut a long story short: 
**If you are using document.location you are not using Ajax and you will not have any transitions**.

Answer (score 0):

Very first point ideally one should not use onclik in anchor tag.
Use some thing like this

`<a href="javascript:loadPage('admin-list-notification.html?');" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Notification</a>`

Comment: Hi Hardik, sorry I am not so expert in javascript..I used href="javascript:loadPage('category.html?');" in my anchor tag..But it's not moving to the category page when I click on that link..Can you please help??

Comment: That is because loadPage is a user defined function that you need to write. So function loadPage(){ //your code }